# CSS3 border-radius on toggle input not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For some reason my toggle button styles are not working in IE11. The input button should be a green circle but it's showing as a square box with a quite background and black border in IE11:

[image]

Here is how it is intended to look:

[image]

My code:

```css
.toggle-field {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0.35rem;
}

.toggle-field .Toggle {
  padding-left: 75px;
}

.toggle-field .toggle-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 68px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.toggle-field input {
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: left 117ms ease;
  border: none;
}

.toggle-field input:focus + .toggle-element {
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.toggle-field b {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 34px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 40px;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
}

.toggle-field .Toggle.On input {
  left: 38px;
  background: #2ea664;
}

.toggle-field .Toggle.On b {
  left: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field toggle-field null">
  <label for="button1" class="Toggle On">
    <input type="checkbox" id="button1" name="button1" value="on">
    <span class="toggle-element"></span>
    <b>YES</b> Question goes here
  </label>
</div>
```

Most of what I have read says that I need to have a certain compatibility tag included, which I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Not sure what else to do. Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />`

Comment: Also related: https://superuser.com/questions/838802/ie11-renders-elements-with-border-radius-incorrectly

Comment: Adding this tag does not fix the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different way of doing this that works in IE11.

```
.toggle-field {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 0.35rem;
}

.toggle-field .Toggle {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.toggle-field input {
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: left 117ms ease;
  border: none;
}

.toggle-field .toggle-element {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 68px;
  height: 32px;
}

.toggle-element:before {
  background-color: #ccc;
  bottom: 3px;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 26px;
}

input:checked + .toggle-element {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input:checked + .toggle-element:before {
  transform: translateX(34px);
  background-color: #2ea664;
}

.toggle-element {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.toggle-element:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

<div class="field toggle-field null">
  <label for="checkbox" class="Toggle On">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <span class="toggle-element"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```